# How to extract create statements from different tables of MySQL DBs?

Tags: mysql, r

I would like to extract all `Create Statements` in my 50 `MySQL` Databases via `SHOW CREATE TABLE db.table` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE db1.mytable`or `SHOW CREATE TABLE db2.sometable`or `SHOW CREATE TABLE db3.mytable1`. Thus each of the DBs has some tables inside `db1(table,mytable...) db2(table1,sometable) and so on`

To illustrate the DBs via a example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM db.table1 m
   LEFT JOIN db1.sometable o ON m.id = o.id
   LEFT JOIN db2.sometables t ON p.id=t.id
   LEFT JOIN db3.sometable s ON s.column='john'


library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)

con <-  dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                    username = "", 
                    password = "",
                    host = "", 
                    port = 3306,
                    dbname= mydbname)#  when using dbs<-dbGetQuery(con ,"SHOW DATABASES") I have to ## dbname= mydbname## to get all DBs
```

Using `dbs<-dbGetQuery(con ,"SHOW DATABASES")`I can extract all 50 Databases in the dbConnection as character vector. I would like loop over each DB in the `dbs`and apply `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to each row/db. I suppose I have to parse the each row/db into `dbname= mydbname`and `dbs<-dbGetQuery(con ,"SHOW CREATE TABLE")`. But I just cant figure out how to make the loops

I tried:

```
apply(dbs, 1, function(row) {
      dbname <- row[]
      for (i in 1:length(dbname)) {

        create<-dbGetQuery(con,"SHOW CREATE TABLE") }

    })
```

But that doesnt seem right. I suppose I have to include the `con` into the loop somehow. Otherwise I'll get:
`Error in .local(drv, ...) : object 'dbname' not found`

So I tried:

```
apply(dbs, 1, function(row) {
      dbname <- row[]
      for (i in 1:length(dbname)) {
                    con <-  dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                    username = "", 
                    password = "",
                    host = "", 
                    port = 3306,
                    dbname= [i])
        create<-dbGetQuery(con,"SHOW CREATE TABLE") }})
```

I suppose that comes close to the solution but I miss something:

```
dbs<-dbGetQuery(con,"show databases")

library(foreach)

foreach(i = 1:(length(dbs))%dopar%{
  query<-paste("SHOW CREATE TABLE",dbs[i])
  creates<-dbGetQuery(con,query)
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this approach of importing a data frame of each database (leaving out the system ones, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `MYSQL`) and their corresponding tables. Then, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements. Finally, merge the original dataframe with binded dataframe of create statements.

Now, the one caveat is tables that repeat names across databases. To return distinct values of such combinations, the `aggregate()` by `head` function is used.

```
con <-  dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                  username = "****", password = "****",
                  host = "****", port = 3306,
                  dbname= "****")
dbtbls <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA` AS `Database`, 
                                  `TABLE_NAME` AS `Table`
                            FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` 
                            WHERE `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
                              AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` NOT LIKE '%SCHEMA%' 
                              AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` NOT LIKE '%MYSQL%' ")
# LIST OF SQL STATEMENTS
sql <- paste0("SHOW CREATE TABLE ", dbtbls$Database, ".", dbtbls$Table)

# LIST OF DATAFRAMES
createstmts <- lapply(sql, function(x) dbGetQuery(con, x))
dbDisconnect(con)

# ROW BIND LIST INTO ONE DATAFRAME TO MERGE WITH ORIGINAL    
stmtsdf <- do.call(rbind, createstmts)
finaldf <- merge(dbtbls, stmtsdf, by='Table')

# RETURN DISTINCT RECORDS
finaldf <- aggregate(.~Database+Table, finaldf, FUN=head, 1)
```

Comment: Thats even better then expected. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @ Parfait. May I ask you one question regarding `stmtsdf <- do.call(rbind, createstmts)` My `creatstmts`is quite huge, almost 2MB and I'll get `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match` Is there a general approach to deal with that?

Comment: I think in my DB are some `View` as well. I suppose that somehow changes the data structure for `rbind`

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Indeed, you are correct, the initial select query pulls in views as well as tables and `CREATE TABLE table` vs `CREATE TABLE view` have different columns and names, hence `do.call()` fails. I add a `WHERE` condition `TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'` to pull in only tables.

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqldump --no-data
```

does exactly what you are asking for.  (There may be other parameters desirable to avoid/include `CREATE DATABASE`, etc.)

If the requirement is to subsequently pull the `CREATEs` into R, then I ask whether this is a one-time task, or a recurring task.  For one-time, I would suggest that, overall, the mysqldump approach might be simpler.

Answer (score -4):

First, you can just simply use

```
for (i in 1:length(dbs)) { }
```

Or you can look into apply functions, particularly, sapply. There you can do parsing per dbConnection string, connect and get all tables as list or vector. Then you can loop inside those to get create table statements.
So, it is basically apply inside apply.
For a good explanation of apply functions, you can look into http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/

Comment: Yes, it seems a have to use a nested loop. Thats why I posted the question. Because I cant implement it. So I assume the first loop has to take the lenght into account. Thank you for the suggestion